# Prosper slide not centered

Tags: slideshow, prosper

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{prosper}

\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\FontText{%
  \black\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\selectfont}{%
  \black\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\selectfont}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\let\familydefault\sfdefault

\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{math example}
  \begin{align*}
    c_k&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-\mathrm{i}kx}\,\mathrm{d}x
    =\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{j=1}^{r}\int_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j} f(x) e^{-\mathrm{i}kx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
    &=\frac{-\mathrm{i}}{2\pi k}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \varphi(x) e^{-\mathrm{i}kx}\,\mathrm{d}x
    =\frac{-\mathrm{i}\gamma_k}{k}\text{.}
  \end{align*}
  As for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathds{C}$,
  $\left|\alpha\beta\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\left|\alpha\right|^2+\left|\beta\right|^2\right)$, it holds that
  \begin{displaymath}
    \left|c_k\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\left|k\right|^2}+\left|\gamma_k\right|^2\right)\text{.}
  \end{displaymath}
  From the convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$ and
  $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\gamma_k\right|^2$, it follows that
  \begin{displaymath}
    \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left|c_k\right|<\infty\text{.}
  \end{displaymath}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

It is an example provided by [this lecture](http://texpower.sourceforge.net/doc/Lecture-LUT-2003.zip) (there's a ZIP file called "mathdemo", inside which there is an example mathdemo12). The example PDF provided looks like this:

[image: Example]

But when I compile it, it gives 
[image]
Notice that the slide is not centered.

I want to know the reason for not making it centered. (My compiler setting is the default setting provided by "LaTeXify2PDF" of WinEdt, which is included in a mod which can be found at the official site of WinEdt).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you committed to using `prosper`, or could you switch to `beamer`?

Comment: Yes I need to use Prosper.